# Big O of all javascript array and object methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, big-o, javascript-objects

Hey guyz currently I am studying the concepts of Big O ,I would like to clear my few question, I am well aware of Big O and its concept but still I couldnt find any proper answer on google related to these questions 
1. What is Big O of all the javascript array method ( specially indexof , includes) 
2. What is big O of all javascript object method ( specially keys,values) 
3. Big o(1) is said to be constant time but what is exact time in terms of ms

Comment: Exact time in terms of ms is platform-dependent and thus is never officially specified.

Comment: Okk can you help me by answering 1st and 2nd question

Comment: As I am new can you explain why my question has been marked as negative.?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but it seems like you want other people to do your homework for you. Stack Overflow is neither a search engine nor a homework completion site.

Comment: @JohnColeman Well its not my homework exactly ,I am currently working as an Software developer as I am trying to implement big o concepts in order to increased standard of ny code and fast working of my code as I am js developer lots of questions came to my mind and google it not many post I found related to js with big o concept, so I publish my queries here so that my queries get cleared as I have less time to implement

Comment: @Adityatoke fair enough. For much of the world, the academic year is drawing to a close and Stack Overflow gets inundated with homework questions, which tend to get downvoted (unless they are phrased well and show some effort on the student's part). It wan't your intention, but that is how your question read. As far as your question goes, it is at least possible that the answer is engine specific. I doubt if the official language specification explicitly dictates asymptotic complexity.

Comment: @JohnColeman Ya engine specific we can say as I tried to read the google chrome v8 engine how its handlation relates to array and object but didnt got success on that part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. What is Big O of all the javascript array method ( specially indexof , includes)

Looking up values in unordered lists is a classical O(n) task: as you do not know where the element is, you just have to start checking them one by one. While technically it is possible to create an "inverse", value->key map for arrays, environments usually just do not do that. For example the V8 engine is not an exception either, see https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/elements.cc, methods like [`IndexOfValueSlowPath`](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/elements.cc#L516)

> ```
> for (uint32_t k = start_from; k < length; ++k) {
> ```

or [`IndexOfValueImpl`](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/elements.cc#L1844)

> ```
> for (uint32_t k = start_from; k < length; ++k) {
> ```

and a couple more instances of them.
They are called from [`Runtime_ArrayIndexOf`](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/runtime/runtime-array.cc#L829), at line [899](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/runtime/runtime-array.cc#L899) specifically. If this method does not apply, there is a fallback a couple lines later, again using a simple for loop (`index` is set earlier, already used for calling the methods mentioned above):

> ```
> for (; index < len; ++index) {
> ```

---

> 2. What is big O of all javascript object method ( specially keys,values)

`Object` is in the neighboring (to array) runtime file, https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/runtime/runtime-object.cc, but do not expect magic there either, it also ends up in various `for` loops in https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/keys.cc, like a simple one [checking](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/keys.cc#L27) if an array is built of valid keys (numbers and strings)

> ```
> static bool ContainsOnlyValidKeys(Handle<FixedArray> array) {
>   int len = array->length();
>   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
>     Object e = array->get(i);
>     if (!(e->IsName() || e->IsNumber())) return false;
>   }
>   return true;
> }
> ```

or another one called from various places to build a single [collection](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/keys.cc#L102) from multiple sources:

> ```
> void KeyAccumulator::AddKeys(Handle<FixedArray> array,
>                              AddKeyConversion convert) {
>   int add_length = array->length();
>   for (int i = 0; i < add_length; i++) {
>     Handle<Object> current(array->get(i), isolate_);
>     AddKey(current, convert);
>   }
> ```

---

> 3. Big o(1) is said to be constant time but what is exact time in terms of ms

There is no such thing.

Comment: Awesome , thanks for big help, cleared almost my every question

Answer (score 0):

> Big o(1) is said to be constant time but what is exact time in terms of ms

The big *O* notation (and small *o*, too, BTW) doesn't represent any specific *value*, it represents the grow of resources needed dependent of the size of the input data. It answers the question: "if I execute my algorithm on data twice as large, will it take just as long, or twice as long, or will get exponentially worse - more or less?".

One nanosecond, a billion years, and any other *specific value* are all O(1).

Regarding computational cost of typical array operations, anything requiring (maybe in the worst-case scenario) looking through an entire array will be at least O(*array's length*). With functional methods like `reduce`, `map` etc., the complexity of the callback functions counts as well - the callback could be O(1), but can also be O(*array's length*), or O(*some another array's length*).

Comment: Is there any way to check the exact big o of any build method of js